# How to get htmlFor of a label

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the `for` attribute of a label element using jQuery. So far all of my attempts have yielded incorrect responses.

```
        console.log($('label'.htmlFor)); //e.fn.init.....
        console.log($('label').htmlFor)); //undefined
        console.log($('label.htmlFor')); //[prevObject.....]..
        console.log($('label[for]')); 
        console.log($('label')); //same as directly above
        console.log($('label[for].htmlFor')); //[prevObject.....]..
        console.log($('label[for]').htmlFor)); //undefined
```

I know the htmlFor is defined as I can see it in chromes web inspector. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$('label').prop('htmlFor')` or `$('label').attr('for')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your examples don't work because you either select the element only (and don't retrieve the attribute value) or you try and get the `htmlFor` attribute which not a valid property of a jQuery object.

To do what you require you need to select the `label` then use `attr()` to get the `for` attribute, like this:

```
var forAttr = $('label[for]').attr('for');
```

Alternatively, if there are multiple `label` elements in your form you can loop through them like this:

```
$('label[for]').each(function() {
   var forAttr = $(this).attr('for');
   // work with for here...
});
```

Comment: Yes, your solution worked. Can you take a look here and tell me why this didn't work like this? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_label_htmlfor.asp

Comment: The difference there is that `getElementById()` returns a DOMElement, which does have the `htmlFor` property. A jQuery object (ie. `$('#foo')`) does not. I would also advise against using W3Schools as a resource. Their articles are quite often outdated and in some cases just plain wrong.

Comment: gotcha, I underastand now